# Bash delete all folders except one that might be nested

Tags: recursion, directory, find

I am trying to work out a way to delete all folders but keep once, even if it is nested.

```
./release/test-folder
./release/test-folder2
./release/feature/custom-header
./release/feature/footer
```

If I run something like:

```
    shopt -s extglob
    rm -rf release/!(test-folder2)/

or
    find ./release -type d -not -regex ".*test-folder2.*" -delete
```

get it OK, but in the cases when path is nested like `feature/footer`

Both command lines matches `release/feature` and it gets deleted.

Can you suggest any other option that would keep the folder, no matter how nested it is?

Answer (score 0):

This is not best solution but it works.

```
# $1 = root path
# $2 = pattern
findex(){
  # create temp dir                                                                       
  T=$(mktemp -d)
  # find all dirs inside "$1"
  # and save it in file "a"
  find "$1" -type d >$T/a
  # filtering file A by pattern "$2"
  # and save it in file "b" 
  cat $T/a | grep "$2" >$T/b
  # For each path in the file b
  # add paths of the parent directories
  # and save it in file "c"
  cat $T/b | while read P; do 
    echo $P 
    while [[ ${#1} -lt ${#P} ]]; do 
      P=$(dirname "$P")
      echo $P
    done
  done >$T/c
  # make list in file "c" unique
  # and save it in file "d"
  cat $T/c | sort -u >$T/d;
  # find from list "a" all the paths 
  # that are missing in the list "d"
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' $T/d $T/a
  # remove temporary directory
  rm -rf $T
}
# find all dirs inside ./path except matching "pattern"
# and remove it
findex ./path "pattern" | xargs -L1 rm
```

Test it

```
findex(){
  T=$(mktemp -d)
  find "$1" -type d >$T/a
  cat $T/a | grep "$2" >$T/b
  cat $T/b | while read P; do 
    echo $P 
    while [[ ${#1} -lt ${#P} ]]; do 
      P=$(dirname "$P")
      echo $P
    done
  done >$T/c
  cat $T/c | sort -u >$T/d;
  # save result in file "e"
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} !($0 in a)' $T/d $T/a >$T/e
  # output path of temporary directory
  echo $T
}
cd $TMPDIR
for I in {000..999}; do 
  mkdir -p "./test/${I:0:1}/${I:1:1}/${I:2:1}"; 
done
T=$(findex ./test "5")
cat $T/a | wc -l  # => 1111 dirs total
cat $T/d | wc -l  # => 382  dirs matched
cat $T/e | wc -l  # => 729  dirs to delete
rm -rf $T ./test
```

Comment: Same problem

`find ./release -type d | grep -v "feature/footer" | xargs -L1 rm` will match folder `./release/feature` and will delete everything under